# What is alternative of the MS SQL "uniqueidentifier" data type for HSQLDB?

Tags: sql-server, hsqldb

In the MS SQL I have the following table and stored proc:

```
CREATE TABLE tAppointment (
  tickCount          INTEGER,
  lastUpdateTz       VARCHAR(32),
  guid               VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  ...
 PRIMARY KEY (guid));

CREATE PROCEDURE pUpdateAppointmentActive (
    @appointmentGuid    uniqueidentifier,
    @active     nvarchar(64)
)
AS

BEGIN

    UPDATE
    dbo.tAppointment
    SET
    active = @active
    WHERE
    guid = @appointmentGuid

END
```

So the question is how to translate "uniqueidentifier" type to the HSQLDB format?

Comment: Do you use SQL Server and do tests with hsqldb?

Comment: @lad2025 nope, hsqldb will be used as embedded db in the my app

Comment: [Probably a `varbinary`](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_data_type_guide) populated by the [`uuid()` function](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#N14217)

Comment: Why is guid a varchar(250) in sql server? If it is a uniqueidentifier that should be the datatype. And if it is going to be the primary key you need a different column for the clustered index or you need to constantly keep defragmenting your clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server `uniqueidentifier` data type corresponds to `UUID` type in HSQLDB.

Comment: This answer will probably get me a Necromancer badge :-)